# How to plot GRU (Gated Recurrent Unit)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I was trying to reproduce the plot for GRU as below. But I can't find a way to generate those switch-like buttons.

[image]

Comment: If you deem my answer below sufficient, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a custom node style `switch`, that has a few custom own keys to be set.

- `open` Rather self-explanatory, boolean toggle that can be set to either true or false, defaults to `true`;
- `closed` The opposite of `open`, thus defaults to `false`;
- `swap` Can be set to swap the direction of the latch.

Additionally I changed the default `label` reference position to be on the first circle.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{tabular}{r l}
                 The default behavior without keys: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw              (0,0) -- node[switch]                          ++(2,0); \\
                 When setting the switch to closed: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw              (0,0) -- node[switch={closed}]                 ++(2,0); \\
    Adding a label, and explicitly set \verb|open|: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw[thick]       (0,0) -- node[switch={open},label={z}]         ++(2,0); \\
                        The style also obeys color: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw[red]         (0,0) -- node[switch={closed},label={below:r}] ++(2,0); \\
                            As well as line widths: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- node[switch={open,swap},label={d}]    ++(2,0); \\
\end{tabular}
```

And to show that it can be placed on various (straight) paths:

[image]

Code:

```
Example in a \verb|tikzpicture|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- node[switch,label={below:q}]  ++(0,-2  )
                -- node[switch={swap}]           ++(2, 0  )
                -- node[switch={closed},label=a] ++(0, 1.5)
                -- node[switch,blue]             ++(2,-1  );
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Note** I normally draw *two* of the black dots to show where the latch should go when it is closed, but if for whatever reason you do not want the second circle, there is a line in the `path picture`-key of the style that can be ignored by placing a `%` before it. I've indicated what line by means of a comment in the MWE.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

%====================================================================================
% START: COPY THIS PART TO YOUR DOCUMENT TO USE THE 'switch' STYLE
%====================================================================================
\makeatletter
\newif\ifswitch@open
\newif\ifswitch@swap

% Keys to be set by 'switch={<keys>}'
\pgfkeys{
    /switch/.cd,
        open/.is if=switch@open,
        open=true,
        closed/.code=\pgfkeysalso{open=false},
        swap/.is if=switch@swap,
}

% Switch tikz style 
\tikzset{
    switch/.style={
        % For placing
        sloped,
        allow upside down,
        midway,
        % For sizing
        inner sep = 0pt,
        minimum height = 7mm+0.5\pgflinewidth,
        minimum width = 8mm+2\pgflinewidth+2pt,
        % Node cannot contain text, so contents are set to {}
        node contents={},
        % Tricky command to adjust the default label position
        prefix after command= {
            \pgfextra{
                \tikzset{
                    every label/.style={
                        shift={(switch@label@coor)},
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        % The drawing of the switch, inside the node
        path picture={%
            \ifswitch@open
                \draw[white,line width=2\pgflinewidth] (-0.4,0) -- (0.4,0);
                \ifswitch@swap
                    \draw (-0.4,0) -- ++(-25:0.8);
                \else
                    \draw (-0.4,0) -- ++(25:0.8);
                \fi
            \fi
            \fill (-0.4,0) coordinate (switch@label@coor) circle (1pt+\pgflinewidth);
            \fill ( 0.4,0) circle (1pt+\pgflinewidth); % Place a '%' before this line to omit the second black circle
        },
    },
    % To be able to accept the keys as argument
    switch/.prefix code={\pgfkeys{/switch/.cd,#1}},
}
\makeatother
%====================================================================================
% END: COPY THIS PART TO YOUR DOCUMENT TO USE THE 'switch' STYLE
%====================================================================================

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r l}
                     The default behavior without keys: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw              (0,0) -- node[switch]                          ++(2,0); \\
                     When setting the switch to closed: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw              (0,0) -- node[switch={closed}]                 ++(2,0); \\
        Adding a label, and explicitly set \verb|open|: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw[thick]       (0,0) -- node[switch={open},label={z}]         ++(2,0); \\
                            The style also obeys color: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw[red]         (0,0) -- node[switch={closed},label={below:r}] ++(2,0); \\
                                As well as line widths: & \tikz[baseline={-0.55ex}] \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- node[switch={open,swap},label={d}]    ++(2,0); \\
    \end{tabular}

    Example in a \verb|tikzpicture|:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- node[switch,label={below:q}]  ++(0,-2  )
                    -- node[switch={swap}]           ++(2, 0  )
                    -- node[switch={closed},label=a] ++(0, 1.5)
                    -- node[switch,blue]             ++(2,-1  );
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**SIDENOTE** I have to mention, I only placed this answer because I already made this style for personal use (call it charity). If you want better or more answers (in the future), you should consider placing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), and include code that you have already tried. This way, the threshold for users will be lower to start experimenting with your question.